# How create entities tables in netbeans without primary key tables from JDE database?

Tags: netbeans, primary-key, entities, jdedwards

We have a JDE (JD Edwards) system on an AS400 DB2 database. There is a Showcase server running queries to create several tables (.dbf). These queries run at different time during the day and night to generate the tables with most current information from JD Edwards and the resulting files are saved in several folders. Also, there are other servers running Scheduled tasks. These Scheduled tasks run also at different time during the day and night to load the data from Showcase to an Oracle database. So, there are around 180 tasks running all day and night to keep the Oracle database updated generating an enormous effort in support and monitoring the system. Finally there is a Netbeans Platform application that uses the Oracle database to show information to the user.
Now, to get rid of the Showcase and Scheduled tasks I had created a connection to JDE database directly from Netbeans. My question is: What kind of Netbeans application project is the most convenient for this system? I tried creating a CRUD form JSF, but the JDE tables don’t have Primary key so I couldn’t create Entities Classes from Database.

Comment: Why don't your JDE tables have primary keys?  They should.